# My main div is stuck over my header div

Tags: css

I am pretty new to this. I am hoping for some help and advise keeping my divs side by side. One is a menu which works fine but now my content is overlapping and I'm not sure what I did. I should make multiple saves. any advice on positioning my divs would be crazy appreciated.

apologies if my formatting of the post is wrong. brain is fried and my website is due for class tomorrow.

```
body {
background-color: #35455e;
}

h1 {    
text-align: center; 
font-size: 400%; 
color: #ecb3ff;
padding-left: 30px;
}

h2 {    
text-align: center;
font-size: 300%;
color: #ecb3ff; 
padding-left: 40px;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
border-style: hidden;
}


a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;  
font-size: 125%;
padding-left: 12px;
}

a:hover {
color: #fff666;
}

a:active {
color: #9bc1ff; 
}

div.header {
background-image: url("https://scontent-sea1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-
9/22089728_10212094710577763_385045730802353501_n.jpg?
oh=534f6bd3108f6f68f96cf5709e404b9f&oe=5AD4BADA");
background-size: initial;
background-repeat: repeat;
border-radius: 8px;
height: 573px;
width: 449px;
border: 10px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #333333;
float: left;
position:fixed;}


div.main{

position: relative;
top: 500px;
right: 500px;

}

li {    
width: 30%; 
}




My HTML:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Madison Queen's Art Portfolio: Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="header">

<h1>Madison Art Portfolio</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Photo.html">Photography</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div><!--closing of header-->




<div class="main">

<h2>Madison Art Portfolio</h2>




</div><!--CLOSING OF MAIN-->








</div><!--CLOSING OF THE CONTAINER-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your html code?

Comment: share your html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `position:fixed;` in div.header and `position:relative;` in div.main you can change the stack of them using `z-index` value in CSS. if you want your header on the front side and main on the back side then add `z-index:2` in div.header and `z-index:1` in div.main.

it is overlapping because you have specified the fixed position to the header which is placing the header on the fixed place and anything on the page will overlap with the header. you can try `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the code from div.main. It's not required. Also remove position: fixed from the div.header block.